# Hiding the inner panel partially using html css

Tags: css

My markup looks like this :

```
<div class='container' style='margin:10em'>
<div class='content'><p>some content here !</p></div>
</div>
```

Now I want to hide '.content' partially, that is imagine it to be shifted half way left side, and  the other half should be visible and not the left half.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
.container { overflow:hidden; }
.content { margin-left:-50px; } /* or any amount you want*/
```

Edit:
margin should be -50px to hide left side.

Comment: Exactly what I thought, except simpler, nice answer.